# Escribir a un vector y guardar info a un archivo

Tags: c++

Buenas!
Estoy intentado implementar la recomendación que me hizo @eferion en una pregunta anterior: [Leer string y floats de un archivo para calcular promedio ponderado en C++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/68078/leer-string-y-floats-de-un-archivo-para-calcular-promedio-ponderado-en-c)

Pero el IDE me arroja varios errores. El código es el siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    // Nombre del programa
    cout << "\t\t Promedio Ponderado\n" << endl;

    int num_Mat;
    string nombre;

    // Solicita el numero de materias
    cout << "Ingrese el numero de materias\n";
    cin >> num_Mat;

    //Crea vectores para la variable Nombres
    vector <string> vNombres;

    // Creación del archivo
    ofstream fNombres;

   // Apertura y comprobación

    if ( !fNombres.open("Nombres.txt") ) {
        cout << "Error al intentar abrir el archivo Nombres" << endl;
    } else {

        // Loop para obtener el nombre de las materias y enviarlas al vector
        for (int i = 0; i < num_Mat; i++){
        cout << "Ingresa el nombre de la materia " << i+1 << endl; // "+1" porque no existe Materia 0
        cin >> vNombres[i] ;
        fNombres << vNombres[i] << endl;
        }
    }

    fNombres.close();                                // Cierra el archivo 1

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Y me arroja los siguientes errores:

1. error: could not convert 'fNombres.std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open >(((const char*)"Nombres.txt"), std::operator|((std::_Ios_Openmode)16u, (std::_Ios_Openmode)32u))' from 'void' to 'bool'|
2. error: in argument to unary !|

Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Además, vi en otra pregunta que para crear un vector, primero escriben el tipo de variable que irá dentro del mismo y luego lo nombran, en cambio aquí, primero se declara el vector y luego se escoge el tipo de variable a utilizar. Fuente: [C++ con vectores](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/15018/c-con-vectores)

¿Al final es lo mismo?

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Sin intención de ofender, pero creo que lo que estás haciendo mal es que no has leído ni los rudimentos del lenguaje. Si me permites un consejo te diré que te busques un tutorial básico que hay muchos o que te compres un libro para principiantes.

Comment: Su comentario no ayuda, pero gracias :)

Comment: En la pregunta que indicas, `vector` es un *arreglo*. Es un elemento propio del lenguaje, que puede entenderse como una *matriz* de 1 sola dimensión. En esta, `vector` es una *clase*, un TAD que pertenece a la librería de C++, y no es un elemento propio del lenguaje. No es lo mismo. La confusión viene por el nombre elegido en aquella, `vector`. Pero **no** son lo mismo.

Comment: Ahora sí entiendo. Muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Los objetos de la familia del flujo de archivos [`std::basic_fstream`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream) como `std::ifstream` y `std::ofstream` tienen un operador de conversión a valor booleano: [`std::basic_fstream::operator bool`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) que devuelve verdadero si el flujo no tiene errores.

Por lo tanto, tu código puede ser escrito así:

```
if ( std::ofstream fNombres{"Nombres.txt"} ) {
    // ...
} else {
    cout << "Error al intentar abrir el archivo Nombres" << std::endl;
}
```

No te hará falta llamar a `fNombres.close()` pues el archivo se cierra automáticamente al salir del bloque del `if`.

#### ¿Cómo funciona esto?

En C++ es posible declarar variables en el cuerpo de una instrucción `if`<sup>1</sup>, estas variables vivirán durante todo el bloque `if` y el bloque `else` (si lo hubiera). Una vez declarada la variable, ésta puede ser usada como valor del lado derecho (conocido como RValue en Inglés).

Dada la existencia del operador de conversión booleano, `fNombres` será evaluado como condición (como si fuese un booleano), si el archivo se ha podido abrir no contendrá errores y entrará en el cuerpo del `if`.

#### ¿Por qué no funciona en tu caso?

> `error: could not convert 'fNombres.std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open >(((const char*)"Nombres.txt"), std::operator|((std::_Ios_Openmode)16u, (std::_Ios_Openmode)32u))' from 'void' to 'bool'`

El error que recibes te indica que no puedes convertir de `void` a `bool`. Esto es porque la función que usas en la condición ([`std::basic_fstream::open`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open)) tiene como tipo de retorno `void`, dicho tipo no puede ser evaluado como condición booleana, pero el compilador lo intenta, fracasa, y se queja:

> `error: no puedo convertir 'fNombres.open("Nombres.txt") de 'void' a 'bool'`

#### `void` no es negable.

> `error: in argument to unary !`

El otro error que recibes es al intentar aplicar el operador unario de negación (`!`) sobre un tipo no negable.

El operador unario de negación (`!`) niega el valor booleano de una expresión booleana o de una expresión convertible a booleana. C++ ofrece conversiones implícitas a booleano para expresiones numéricas (siendo `0` considerado falso y cualquier cosa diferente a `0` considerada verdadera) pero `void` es uno de los tipos que no puede ser evaluado como booleano.

#### No es todo...

Una vez corregidos los errores en tiempo de compilación, el programa te fallará en tiempo de ejecución, la respuesta de [Mario Rodríguez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/76151/2742) explica perfectamente los errores que te encontrarás, échale un vistazo.

---

<sup>1</sup>También en la instrucción `switch` y `while`

Comment: No pudo haberlo explicado mejor. Todo quedó completamente entendible y le agradezco mucho por tomarse el tiempo de explicar cada pequeño detalle. Muchas gracias! Bendiciones.

Answer (score 1):

El error se encuentra en la comprobación de si el fichero se ha abierto correctamente. En ese caso **open** no devuelve un valor *booleano*, por lo que puedes cambiarlo por una función que sí que devuelva lo que necesitas como por ejemplo:

```
fNombres.open("Nombres.txt", ios::out);
```

Y luego, para comprobar si se ha podido abrir (y no intentar leer de un fichero inexistente) **is_open**:

```
if ( !fNombres.is_open() ) { ... }
```

Además, el código que planteas dará algún problema más a la hora de añadir elementos al vector, ya que se está intentando acceder a posiciones que aún no existen en él. Más concretamente en:

```
cin >> vNombres[i] ;
```

Para poder hacer eso antes debes de inicializar el vector con tantas posiciones como número de materias a incluir posteriormente.

```
vector <string> vNombres(num_Mat,"");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la rápida respuesta!
Es cierto que, si en lugar de cin `>> vNombres[i] ;` uso `push_back` ya no tendría que inicializar el vectores con la cantidad de posiciones que deseo usar?

Comment: Pero mi duda es exactamente esa, en un respuesta de @eferion, el usó lo mismo que yo estoy usando: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/68078/leer-string-y-floats-de-un-archivo-para-calcular-promedio-ponderado-en-c/68107#68107
Pero por qué no funciona cuando lo hago yo ?
Gracias!

Comment: Porque tú lo que estás intentando abrir es un fichero de salida (ofstream) que aún no existe, mientras que en el ejercicio que indicas el archivo es de entrada (ifstream). No sé si era eso a lo que te referías.

Comment: Con respecto a lo de no inicializar vectores, sí que puedes hacerlo de otra manera. Puedes crear una nueva variable auxiliar de tipo `string` para redirigir la entrada sobre ésta y, posteriormente, añadir esta variable en el vector. Resumiendo: `cin >> aux ; vNombres.push_back(aux) ;`

Comment: Comprendo perfectamente. Muchísimas gracias !