# Como manejar ficheros de textos para guardar puntajes de un juego?

Tags: c++, poo, sfml

La idea es que al morir el usuario ingresa su nombre y este se guarda junto con su puntaje manteniendo los nombre y puntajes que ya estaban guardados. el problema es que el codigo que tengo solamente sobreescribe el archivo anterior y guarda el ultimo nombre ingresado. Probe abriendo el fichero y asando todos los datos dentro de este a un string auxiliar pero la unica forma de leer datos de un fichero de texto que conozco es **.getline()** y esta funcion utiliza **char** en vez de **string**

este es el codigo:

al morir el jugador se ingresa el nombre.

```
    if (aircraft.isDead(false)){
        bool flag = false;

        text.setString("Juego Terminado \n Ingresa tu nombre:");
        text.setPosition(200, 200);

        if (event.type == sf::Event::TextEntered){
            if (event.text.unicode < 128 && event.text.unicode != 13){
                name.push_back(static_cast<char>(event.text.unicode));
                playerName.setPosition(200, 300);
                playerName.setString(name);
            }
            if (event.text.unicode == 13){
                Save(name);

            }
        }
    }
```

la funcion Save:

```
void Game::Save(std::string nombre){
std::ofstream archivo("Puntajes.txt");

if (archivo.is_open()){
    aircraft.saveScore(archivo, nombre);
}
archivo.close();
}
```

la funcion saveScore de la clase aircraft:

```
void Aircraft::saveScore(std::ofstream &archivo, std::string nombre){
archivo << '\n'+nombre+": "+scorestr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problema.

Tienes que abrir el archivo en modo de agregar datos. El modo de apertura de archivo por defecto es sobre-escritura.

No tendrías este problema si hubieras leído la documentación disponible sobre la utilidad [`std::ofstream`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream), así que la solución sería...

#### Solución.

Lee la documentación disponible sobre la utilidad [`std::ofstream`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream).

#### Descripción del problema, paso a paso.

La clase `std::ofstream` es una abstracción de flujo de salida de datos de la familia `std::ostream` (igual que `std::cout`)

**Constructor**.

`std::ofstream` se especializada en enviar datos a archivo, dispone de 7 constructores (uno de ellos borrado y tres de ellos dependientes de `std::filesystem` de C++17) pero sólo uno de ellos es relevante para esta pregunta:

- `explicit basic_ofstream( const char* filename, std::ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::out );`

  Crea un flujo de salida de datos a archivo apuntando al archivo identificado por el primer parámetro, si no se especifica nada el segundo parámetro obtiene el valor `std::ios_base_out`.

**Modos de apertura**.

El segundo parámetro del constructor que estás usando especifica los modos de apertura del archivo, es un parámetro de tipo [`std::ios_base::openmode`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode). Hay seis modos de apertura disponibles pero sólo uno de ellos es adecuado a tus necesidades:

- `std::ios_base::app` Significa *añadir* (`app`end). Tras abrir el archivo sitúa el puntero de escritura al final del mismo.

#### Propuesta.

Cambia tu función `Game::Save` de la siguiente manera:

```
void Game::Save(std::string nombre){
    if (std::ofstream archivo{"Puntajes.txt", std::ios_base::app}){
        aircraft.saveScore(archivo, nombre);
    }
}
```

Más detalles de cómo funciona el código anterior [en esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76134/escribir-a-un-vector-y-guardar-info-a-un-archivo/76286#76286).

Comment: Probé el código sugerido pero no hay cambios respecto al que usaba antes, se sobre escribe el fichero y se reemplaza por el ultimo nombre ingresado

Comment: Perdón, el modo debía ser `std::ios_base::app`.