# ¿Cómo podría seguir leyendo un txt sin usar .eof en c++?

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un login de usuario con archivos y tengo una gran duda, cuando uso mi `while(!read.eof)` supuestamente debería leer cada línea de mi txt y continuar con mi orden, pero solo me está leyendo la primera línea, no me reconoce a las demás líneas. ¿Por qué puede ser?

Éste es mi código:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

struct escribir{
    string usuario;
    string pass;
}escribire;

bool isloggedin(){

    string un,pw;

    cout<<"Ingrese su ID:  ";
    cin>>escribire.usuario;
    cout<<"Ingrese su password:  ";
    cin>>escribire.pass;

    ifstream read;

    read.open("texto.txt",ios::in);

    if(read.is_open()){
        while(!read.eof()){
            read>>un>>pw;

            if(un==escribire.usuario && pw==escribire.pass){    
                return true;
            } else{    
                return false;
            }
        }

        read.close();
    }
}

int main(){

    int choice;
    string un,pw;

    cout<<"1.registrar"<<endl;
    cout<<"2.loguearse "<<endl;
    cin>>choice;

    switch(choice){
        case 1:
            {
                ofstream file;
                string nombret;

                cout<<"Ingrese el ID : ";
                cin>>escribire.usuario;
                cout<<"Ingrese el password: l";
                cin>> escribire.pass;

                file.open("texto.txt",ios::app);
                file<<escribire.usuario <<" "<<escribire.pass<<endl;
                file.close();

                main();
            }
        case 2:
            {
                bool status=isloggedin();

                if(!status){
                    cout<<"Error en su contraseña y/o user "<<endl;
                    system("Pause");
                    return 0;
                }else{
                    cout<<"Usted ingreso con exito  "<<endl;
                    system("PAUSE");
                    return 0;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me alegro que no quieras usar [`std::basic_ios::eof`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof) pero no por los motivos que crees.

La función que comprueba la marca de final de archivo `std::basic_ios::eof` no debe ser usada como condición de continuidad de bucle. Es un error común considerar que llamar a `std::basic_ios::eof()` indicará el final del archivo previniendo la lectura, al contrario: la marca de final de archivo se establece **después** de la lectura; esto provoca que puedas intentar leer datos habiendo alcanzado el final de archivo, imagina la siguiente situación:
[image]
El puntero de lectura está a dos "datos" del final, en estos momentos la marca de final de archivo tiene valor `false`, imagina que lees los dos datos restantes:
[image]
El puntero de lectura ha alcanzado el final de archivo pero la marca de final de archivo sigue teniendo valor `false` porque aún no has leído el final de archivo, así pues: la condición de salida del bucle no se cumpliría y entrarías a intentar leer datos aunque no hubiera datos que leer:

```
while(!read.eof()){
    // Nos creemos que NO hemos llegado al final del archivo
    // aunque en realidad si que hemos llegado!!
    read>>un>>pw;
    // ... hemos intentado leer datos pero no habia datos, el
    // stream se queda en estado erroneao
}
```

Si quieres usar un bucle para leer los datos, no confíes en `eof()` si no en el operador de conversión a booleano del flujo:

```
while(read>>un>>pw){ // mientras pueda leer...
    // ...
}
```

Una vez aclarado que `eof()` no era el candidato para esta tarea, hay que indicar (tal y como ha mencionado [Jacobo Córdova](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/79735/2742)) el error en tu algoritmo: en una primera lectura tanto si encuentras como si no al usuario buscado, sales (con verdadero o falso) de la función de búsqueda, ignorando el resto de registros en tu archivo. La manera adecuada de enfocar este problema sería usar una *variable de arrastre* cuyo valor será devuelto al finalizar la búsqueda:

```
bool isloggedin(){

    std::string un,pw;

    std::cout << "Ingrese su ID:  ";
    std::cin >> escribire.usuario;
    std::cout << "Ingrese su password:  ";
    std::cin >> escribire.pass;

    // Antes de empezar a buscar, asumimos
    // que el usuario no ha sido encontrado.
    bool encontrado = false;

    for (std::ifstream read{"texto.txt"}; read && !encontrado; read >> un >> pw)
    {
        encontrado = (un == escribire.usuario && pw == escribire.pass);
    }

    return encontrado;
}
```

El código anterior abre el archivo `"texto.txt"` en el bucle `for` (no es necesario especificar modo `std::ios_base::in`, ya que es el modo por defecto de `std::ifstream`) y lo recorre registro a registro hasta encontrar un registro que coincida con el buscado, en cuyo caso finalizará el bucle `for`, cerrando automáticamente el archivo (no es necesario llamar explícitamente a `.close()` pues se llama implícitamente al finalizar el bucle). Para tener más detalles de cómo funciona el flujo de archivo como valor booleano [consulta este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76134/escribir-a-un-vector-y-guardar-info-a-un-archivo/76286#76286).

Comment: Vale! tienes razon. ↑ esta es la respuesta

Comment: Agradezco que me ayudes ,acabo de corregir mi error en mi bool :)

Answer (score 1):

## Tu uso de eof() esta bien!

Lo que no esta bien es tu lógica para acceder a los passwords, estas únicamente comprobando la primera linea; si es quien buscas (en la primera linea) retornas verdadero, y si no es retornas falso. por lo tanto lo que debes hacer es quitar el retorno falso y dejar que la función lea todo el archivo. Mucho ojo ;) ademas debes cerrar el archivo antes de salir de la función.

```
bool isloggedin(){

    string un,pw;

    cout<<"Ingrese su ID:  ";
    cin>>escribire.usuario;
    cout<<"Ingrese su password:  ";
    cin>>escribire.pass;

    ifstream read;

    read.open("texto.txt",ios::in);

    if(read.is_open()){
        while(!read.eof()){
            read>>un>>pw;

            if(un==escribire.usuario && pw==escribire.pass){    
                //si vas a retornar cierra el archivo
                read.close();
                return true;
            } else{    
              //  return false;   <---- aqui esta tu error
              // si no es el primer usuario la funcion retorna falso
            }
        }

        read.close();
    }
    //debes colocar el return al final 
    // y así acabas con el error
    return false;
}
```

Comment: El uso de `eof` en bucles no es correcto, puedes acabar intentando leer datos aún habiendo llegado al final del archivo.

Answer (score 0):

Reglas para el uso de fin de archivo (eof ()):

1. Siempre pruebe la condición de fin de archivo antes de procesar los datos leídos de un flujo de archivos de entrada.
   a. Utilice una instrucción de entrada de priming antes de iniciar el bucle
   segundo. Repetir la instrucción de entrada en la parte inferior del cuerpo de bucle
2. Utilice un bucle while para obtener datos de una secuencia de archivos de entrada. Un bucle for sólo es deseable cuando se conoce el número exacto de elementos de datos en el archivo, que no sabemos.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <fstream.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main(void)
{
     int data;           // file contains an undermined number of integer values
     ifstream fin;     // declare stream variable name

     fin.open("myfile",ios::in);    // open file
     assert (!fin.fail( ));     
     fin >> data;        // get first number from the file (priming the input statement)
                              // You must attempt to read info prior to an eof( ) test.
     while (!fin.eof( ))      //if not at end of file, continue reading numbers
     {
          cout<<data<<endl;    //print numbers to screen
          fin >> data;               //get next number from file
     }
     fin.close( );       //close file
     assert(!fin.fail( ));
     return 0;
}
```

Se ha sabido que la función eof () es persnickety bajo ciertas condiciones. Si experimenta problemas con la función, quizás desee considerar este enfoque alternativo para comprobar el final del archivo:

```
// Este ejemplo crea un archivo de apstrings
// a continuación, abre el nuevo archivo e imprime la información en la pantalla


#include<iostream.h>
#include<fstream.h>
#include<stdlib.h>               //for exit()
#include "apstring.cpp"

int main(void)
{
     ofstream fout;
     ifstream fin;
     apstring sentences, sent;

     fout.open("sentences.dat");  //creating the file
     if (!fout)
     {
          cerr<<"Unable to open file"<<endl;
          exit(1);
     }
     for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)                //file will contain 5 apstring variables
     fout<<"This is sentence #"<<i+1<<endl;
     fout.close( );
    //open file and read from file
     fin.open("sentences.dat");      //open file to access information
     while (getline(fin,sent))   //The test condition is TRUE
                                                  // only while there is something to read.
     {                                           //Works nicely as an end of file check.
          cout<<sent<<endl;
     }
     fin.close( );
     return 0;
}
```

Espero que te sirva.

[Fuente](http://mathbits.com/MathBits/CompSci/Files/End.htm)

Comment: ¿Qué significa *persnickety*? Tu código no compila: las cabeceras de C++ carecen de extensión, y los tipos de la librería estándar están bajo el espacio de nombres `std` que tú omites y no añades una cláusula `using`.

Comment: oh perdon me faltaron los estandares , pero como que no compila ? ,este ejemplo si compila en mi compilador deja ver que paso

Comment: No compila porque como he mencionado, las cabeceras en C++ carecen de extensión, no hay que definir `main` recibiendo `void` nadie (excepto aparentemente tú) tiene `"apstring.cpp"` para incluirlo y te falta una cláusula `using` o anteponer `std::` a los tipos de la STL.